# How do I add an operator to Bash in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I'd like to add an operator ( e.g. ^> ) to handle prepend instead append (>>). Do I need to modify Bash source or is there an easier way (plugin, etc)?

Comment: Why not simply `cat source destination > destination?`

Comment: @m0skit0 that will truncate destination before doing anything else, so you lose what was in it.

Comment: True. In fact it shows an error. I [found](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-prepend-text-lines-to-file/) this: `echo "text" | cat - yourfile > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out yourfile`

Comment: you have to be careful about what you mean because that operator would not work on many kinds of files.

Comment: To be completely clear, I'm not looking to create an external Alias or named function. I want to add an operator. If I clobber a binary file, that's my problem. :-)

Comment: Besides having to heavily modify bash sourcecode, I suspect that will get very slow very fast as you'd have to completely rewrite the destination file whenever the pipe buffer gets flushed.

Comment: If you have to hack a critical piece of infrastructure, how about modifying the file system instead? Sparse files you can prepend to could have their uses.

Comment: BTW, the "^>" was merely an example. I'm not really hung up on the specific characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` is a poor choice of character, as it is already used in [history substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators).

---

To add a new redirection type to the shell grammar, start in `parse.y`.  Declare it as a new `%token` so that it may be used, add it to `STRING_INT_ALIST other_token_alist[]` so that it may appear in output (such as error messages), update the `redirection` rule in the parser, and update the lexer to emit this token upon encountering the appropriate characters.

`command.h` contains `enum r_instruction` of redirection types, which will need to be extended.  There's a giant `switch` statement in `make_redirection` in `make_cmd.c` processing redirection instructions, and the actual redirection is performed by functions throughout `redir.c`.  Scattered throughout the rest of source code are various functions for printing, copying, and destroying pipelines, which may also need to be updated.

That's all!  Bash isn't really *that* complex.

---

This doesn't discuss how to *implement* a prepending redirection, which will be difficult as the UNIX file API only provides for appending and overwriting.  The only way to prepend to a file is to rewrite it entirely, which (as other answers mention) is significantly more complex than any existing shell redirections.

Comment: Thank you for directly addressing my question and not decaying into strategy about algorithms, purpose or other implementation details.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you'd need to modify bash sources and quite heavily. Because, above all, your `^>` would be really hard to implement.

Note that bash redirection operators usually do a very simple writes, and work on a single file (or program in case of pipes) only. Excluding very specific solutions, you usually can't write to a beginning of a file for the very simple reason you'd need to move all remaining contents forward after each write. You *could* try doing that but it will be hard, very ineffective (since every write will require re-writing the whole file) and very unsafe (since with any error you will end up with random mix of old and new version).

That said, you are indeed probably better off with a function or any other solution which would use a temporary file, like others suggested.

For completeness, my own implementation of that:

```
prepend() {
    local tmp=$(tempfile)
    if cat - "${1}" > "${tmp}"; then
        mv "${tmp}" "${1}"
    else
        rm -f "${tmp}"
        # some error reporting
    fi
}
```

Note that you unlike @jpa suggested, you should be writing the concatenated data to a temporary file as that operation *can fail* and if it does, you don't want to lose your original file. Afterwards, you just replace the old file with new one, or delete the temporary file and handle the failure any way you like.

Synopsis the same as with the other solution:

```
echo test | prepend file.txt
```

---

And a bit modified version to retain permissions and play safe with symlinks (if that is necessary) like `>>` does:

```
prepend() {
    local tmp=$(tempfile)
    if cat - "${1}" > "${tmp}"; then
        cat "${tmp}" > "${1}"
        rm -f "${tmp}"
    else
        rm -f "${tmp}"
        # some error reporting
    fi
}
```

Just note that this version is actually *less safe* since if during second `cat` something else will write to disk and fill it up, you'll end up with incomplete file.

To be honest, I wouldn't personally use it but handle symlinks and resetting permissions externally, if necessary.

Comment: On the other hand, creating a new file discards any permissions that may have been set on the file. It also does not work if the file is a symbolic link.

Comment: @jpa: I've added a second version which handles that but well, I'd rather not use it, and modify permissions/handle symlinks myself if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Might be quite difficult to add an operator, but perhaps a function could be enough?

```
function prepend { tmp=`tempfile`; cp $1 $tmp; cat - $tmp > $1; rm $tmp; }
```

Example use:

```
echo foobar | prepend file.txt
```

prepends the text "foobar" to file.txt.

Answer (score 0):

I think bash's plugin architecture (loading shared objects via the 'enable' built-in command) is limited to providing additional built-in commands. The redirection operators are part of they syntax for running simple commands, so I think you would need to modify the parser to recognize and handle your new `^>` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux filesystems do not support prepending. In fact, I don't know of any one that has a stable userspace interface for it. So, as stated by others already, you can only rely on **overwriting**, either just the initial parts, or the entire file, depending on your needs.

You can easily (partially) overwrite initial file contents in Bash, without truncating the file:

```
    exec {fd}<>"$filename"
    printf 'New initial contents' >$fd
    exec {fd}>&-
```

Above, `$fd` is the file descriptor automatically allocated by Bash, and `$filename` is the name of the target file. Bash opens a new read-write file descriptor to the target file on the first line; this does **not** truncate the file. The second line overwrites the initial part of the file. The position in the file advances, so you can use multiple commands to overwrite consecutive parts in the file. The third line closes the descriptor; since there is only a limited number available to each process, you want to close them after you no longer need them, or a long-running script might run out.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `>` does less than you expected:

1. Remove the `>` and the following word from the commandline, remembering the redirection.
2. When the commandline is processed and the command can be launched, calling `fork(2)` (or `clone(2)`), to create a new process.
3. **Modify the new process according to the command.** That includes things like modified environment variables (`SOMEVAR=foo yourcommand`), but also changed filedescriptors. At this point, a `> yourfile` from the cmdline will have the effect that the file is `open(2)`'ed at the stdout filedescriptor (that is #1) in write-only mode **truncating the file to zero bytes**. A `>> yourfile` would have the effect that the file is oppend at stdout in write-only mode **and append mode**.
4. (Only now launch the program, like `execv(yourprogram, yourargs)`

The redirections could, for a simple example, be implemented like

```
open(yourfile, O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC);
```

or

```
open(yourfile, O_WRONLY|O_APPEND);
```

respectively.

The program then launched will have the correct environment set up, and can happily write to fd1. From here, **the shell is not involved**. The real work is not done by the shell, but by the operating system. As Unix doesn't have a prepend mode (and it would be impossible to integrate that feature correctly), everything you could try would end up in a very lousy hack.

Try to re-think your requirements, there's always a simpler way around.